# Making a score value that counts up instead of resetting back to zero

Tags: python, variables

I am working on a Python program. I have the following code:

```py
def AIScoreIncreaseParameter(parameter):
    return parameter+ 1

def AIScoreIncrease():
    scoreBoardAI=0
    print(scoreBoardAI)
    scoreBoardAI=AIScoreIncreaseParameter(scoreBoardAI)
    print(scoreBoardAI)

AIScoreIncrease()
AIScoreIncrease()
```

This is a snippet of a larger set of code I am using for a scoreboard for a game of rock paper scissors. I can't figure out how to have a non-global variable for a scoreboard score that counts up each time a function is called. This code just prints out `(0101)` when I want it to increase in value by one each time to `(0102)`, but to define the variable I have to give it a value, which is zero. How can I fix this? I have run into this same issue another time and it severely limits the scope of the types of game recreations I can make as most games have a counting system that changes (score, currency, card values, etc.).

Comment: You can use the solution of @SurajShourie or you need a global variable or a class variable or an instance variable (attribute) of an object. A local variable can't work.

Comment: @Michael Butscher
A local variable within a function closure is a good way to meet this requirement. See my answer below. A class or instance attribute complicates the name but this is still globally accessible.

Comment: If you have a new problem, post another question, don't add new problems to the same question if there are already answers addressing the original problem.

Comment: oh, I am fairly new here, will do @mkrieger1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to do this to avoid a global variable or globally-accessible name is with a local variable 'hidden' within a function closure.The code below shows an example of how this can be done:

```
def get_next_num():
    num = 0
    started = False
    def inner_num():
        nonlocal  num, started
        if started:
            num += 1
        else:
            started = True
        return num
    return inner_num

next_num = get_next_num()

print(next_num())
print(next_num())
print(next_num())
```

gives:

```
0
1
2
```

The code above ,could if required, be modified to allow a starting value (eg. other than 0) to be set by calling the function rather than 'hard coding' the value in the code. It would also be possible to rewrite the code as a function decorator which counts how many times some arbitrary function has been called.

Comment: Your code doesn't work for my particular issue I don't think as I have all of this in another function that runs the game as a whole. So every time I call the larger function it runs my equivalent to your get_next_num function and resets the value back to zero.

Comment: I don't really understand. Can't you just move  'once only' code outside your game function.

Comment: I currently have the code that would determine the score as a function within the larger function of the game itself. I have it like this as the conditionals that determine score are also in that larger function. The whole game's code is called again each time it is played, resetting the value back to zero where the variable is first defined. I posted another question about this at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76891205/making-a-score-value-within-a-nested-function-that-does-not-reset-to-zero-in-pyt to show what I mean.

Comment: I responded to your new question. Maybe I am missing something about your intentions, but I can't see any reason not to just move the code around as in the new answer. If this is still not what you want then please explain.