# Making a score value within a nested function that does not reset to zero in python

Tags: python

How would I get this to print 1234 instead of 0000 for the purposes of a scoreboard with code that gets three nested functions deep?

```
def game():
    def increasePlayerScore():
        scoreBoardPlayer=0  
        started=False

        def playerScoreIncrease():
            nonlocal scoreBoardPlayer, started   
            if started:
                scoreBoardPlayer+=1
            else: 
                started=True
            return scoreBoardPlayer
        return playerScoreIncrease
    
    newPlayerScore=increasePlayerScore()
    print (newPlayerScore())
game()
game()
game()
game()
```

The goal is to have this count up from 0 to whatever number, but because the game function itself (not shown in this section of code) needs to be called and the scoreboard is inside of it it resets back to zero every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just move the code outside the game function definition:

```
def increasePlayerScore():
    scoreBoardPlayer=1  
    started=False

    def playerScoreIncrease():
        nonlocal scoreBoardPlayer, started   
        if started:
            scoreBoardPlayer+=1
        else: 
            started=True
        return scoreBoardPlayer
    return playerScoreIncrease
    
newPlayerScore=increasePlayerScore()


def game():
    print (newPlayerScore())

game()
game()
game()
game()
```

gives

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much, I could not figure any of that out for the life of me. I still hardly understand why it works, but I'll figure it out now that I have a working example.